# jpa検索機能作成

Tags: java, jpa

検索バーに名前を打ち込んでテーブル内のデータをviewへ表示させたいのですがうまくいきません。

例）「た」と打ち込んで「たなか」「たむら」をヒットさせる

createNamedQueryのsetParameterメソッドを利用して引数を動的に取得するようにしていますが
複数のレコードを取得できない状態です。

例）「た」と打ち込むと「Operand should contain 1 column(s)」とのエラーが表示される。

あいまい検索で複数のレコードを取得するにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。

クエリ文

```
query = "SELECT r FROM Report AS r WHERE r.employee = :employee"
query = "SELECT e FROM Employee AS e WHERE e.name LIKE :name"
```

コントローラ

```
 String employee_name = request.getParameter("search");

        //クエリの結果を変数へ格納、該当する名前のレコードを取得
        try{List<Employee> employee_search = em.createNamedQuery("getEmployeesName" , Employee.class)
                .setParameter("name",employee_name + "%" )
                .getResultList();

        System.out.println(employee_search);

        //レポートテーブル内データ取得
        List<Report> r_employee_id = em.createNamedQuery("getCreateUser" , Report.class)
                .setParameter("employee", employee_search)
                .getResultList();
        em.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと見での回答になりますが、1つ目のSQL（`getEmployeesName`）で複数件のレコードが取得できるのに対し、それらのレコードを検索条件にする2つ目のSQL（`getCreateUser`）は1件しか想定していないWHERE句（`=`での比較）になっています。そのため、

```
query = "SELECT r FROM Report AS r WHERE r.employee = :employee"
```

は、

```
query = "SELECT r FROM Report AS r WHERE r.employee IN :employee"
```

のようにしなければ、動作しないと思います。